# Conftest verify fixture data

Tags: open-policy-agent, conftest

I have been writing a few policies using Conftest and wish to verify my configuration with the `conftest verify` command. So far I have been able to successfully verify my policies like so

```
test_deployment_with_security_context {
  no_violations with input as {
     ... json content ...
  }
}
```

However the omitted JSON content above is rather large and clutters my policy tests. I want to put the JSON into a file and import it into the test. The `conftest verify` command takes a `--data` flag allowing files to be loaded as data and made available to the policies. For example, as per the documentation, `conftest verify --data policy` will recursively load in YAML and JSON files it finds. Therefore a file located in `policy/examples/input.json` is made available within the policies under `import data.examples`. My question is how can I use this data in the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/conftest/issues/535) around this - the docs currently reflect *OPA's* behavior of recursively reading data files from dirs and using directory names for namespacing. This behavior is currently *not* mirrored in conftest. I'd suggest tracking the ticket for progress on that. As a workaround until then you could always "namespace" the data yourself, so that your input.json looks something like this:

```json
{
  "examples": {
     "actual_data": {
        ...
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. I'll keep track of that issue too